# PHP - Use array values to meet a certain condition and do action

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this piece of code in my page:

```
  $options = array("Repairing", "In guarantee", "Ended", "On Hold", "Waiting for quote");
?>
 <select name='estadoRep[]' id='estadoRep'>
     <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>"<?php if ($estadoR[$i] == $option): ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>
             <?php echo $option; ?>
         </option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code will send the status of equipment through a form to another page.

When I "receive" those value through the POST method on the other page, I have the need to fill up a variable if all status in the array = "Ended". If all array[%i] = "Ended" the variable $status should be filled with: "Concluded" else if only one as different value the variable should be filled with "Pending";

I tried the following code but it is not working. Can you please give me some advice? Thanks

```
 $estadoEquip   =   $_POST['estadoRep'];

    $max = sizeof($estadoEquip);
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
      if ($estadoEquip[$i] = 'Ended')
      $status= 'Concluded';

      if ($estadoEquip[$i] != 'Ended')
      $status= 'Pending'; 

    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a synthax error in your php code : 
      if ($estadoEquip[$i] == 'Ended')
      $status= 'Concluded';

Your forgot the double "==", so your $estadoEquip are all equal to "Ended".

Comment: I tried but it didn't work
Equipment XPTO1 - Ended
Equipment XPTO2 - Ended
Equipment XPTO3 - Pending
Works fine and the variable $status='Pending' because the Ended condition was not met for all
Another example:
Equipment XPTO1 - Pending
Equipment XPTO2 - Repairing
Equipment XPTO3 - Ended
Doesn't work fine: The variable $status='Concluded' even though the other two does not met the condition to set the variable that way. It should be also $status='Pending'
My need is that $status='Ended' only if 
Equipment XPTO1 - Ended
Equipment XPTO2 - Ended
Equipment XPTO3 - Ended

Comment: try :    $max = sizeof($estadoEquip);
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
      if ($estadoEquip[$i] == 'Ended'){
         $status= 'Concluded';
   }
   else if ($estadoEquip[$i] != 'Ended'){
  $status= 'Pending'; 
   }
    }

Comment: Remains the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You should put "==" instead of "=" at the "if ($estadoEquip[$i] = 'Ended')"
Otherwise that condition will always be true due to the fact that the variable will always be able to get that value. A simple "=" is not a comparison.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work Equipment XPTO1 - Ended Equipment XPTO2 - Ended Equipment XPTO3 - Pending Works fine and the variable $status='Pending' because the Ended condition was not met for all Another example: Equipment XPTO1 - Pending Equipment XPTO2 - Repairing Equipment XPTO3 - Ended Doesn't work fine: The variable $status='Concluded' even though the other two does not met the condition to set the variable that way. It should be also $status='Pending' My need is that $status='Ended' only if Equipment XPTO1 - Ended Equipment XPTO2 - Ended Equipment XPTO3 - Ended

Answer (score 0):

Some fundamental errors here that I can see:

1 estadoRep (name) does not need to be an array, unless you are doing something tricky to make it a multiple select.

```
 <select name='estadoRep' id='estadoRep'>
     <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>"<?php if ($estadoR[$i] == $option): ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>
             <?php echo $option; ?>
         </option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Your form handler then only needs to use that single incoming variable.

So its much simpler and more comprehensible, if not 'Ended' else status is Pending,

```
  $estadoEquip   =   $_POST['estadoRep'];

  if ($estadoEquip == 'Ended'){
    $status= 'Concluded';
  } else { 
    $status= 'Pending'; 
  }
```

Maybe contentious, but you could simply write that as :

```
$status = ($_POST['estadoRep'] == 'Ended') ? 'Concluded' : 'Pending';
```

Example of Ternary Operator

(untested)

Comment: I used an array because I have the need to send multiple states per multiple equipments from the "front page". I do not have only one equipment and, consequently one state. I can have much more. Thank you.

Comment: In that case all your `name=` values will have to be different.  HTML forms only send one option per select.  Try making a few selects and use var_dump($_POST) in the handler and you should see.